# cannot bind dropdown with List in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Can't bind dropdown with List in AngularJS:

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="x in list">{{x}}</option>
</select>

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $Scope.list=[{id:1, name='name 1'},{id:2, name='name 2'}];
});
```

Comment: you have a typo.. `$scope` not `$Scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a right object and use the correct name of  `$scope` while object names are case sensitive in JavaScript. Check this [runnable fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b9zdy554/) and compare it with your solution.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{
            id: 1, 
            name: 'name 1'
        },{
            id: 2, 
            name: 'name 2'
        }
    ];
});
```

#### view

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="x in list" value="x.id">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, i think it should be "x.id" instead of "x.value"

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this:

Json object was wrong:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.list=[{id:1, name:'name 1'},{id:2, name:'name 2'}];
    });

<select>
    <option ng-repeat="x in list">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>


Or, 

<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item for item in list">
</select>
```